# How do I execute the sbt-web asset pipeline, specifically sbt-concat, before the tests are run?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-web, sbt-concat

I need a JavaScript file to exist before the tests are run. It is created using sbt-concat. How do I add the sbt-web asset pipeline as a dependency to running our spec tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try something like

```
(test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (packageBin in Assets)
```

Comment: Maybe? I get a type mismatch

```[error]  found   : sbt.TaskKey[Unit]
[error]  required: sbt.Task[Unit] => ?
[error]       (test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (assets)```

Comment: My bad, it should have been `test <<= test in Test dependsOn WebKeys.assets`. Will fix the answer

Comment: That didn't work either. But it did point me towards this which worked ```(test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (packageBin in Assets)```